# Sequence with no cache for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I'm trying to migrate from Oracle to PostgreSql.

I have this script for Oracle:

```
create sequence MY_SEQ
    nocache;
```

And nocache is not a valid for PostgreSQl. Any suggestion for postgresql for the equivelant of the nocache?

Answer (score 3):

According the the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) you can use the `cache` option with a value of `1`.

> **cache**
> The optional clause CACHE cache specifies how many sequence numbers are to be preallocated and stored in memory for faster access.
> The minimum value is 1 (only one value can be generated at a time,
> i.e., no cache), and this is also the default.

The documentation also implies that no cache is the default, so you can omit it.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't specify it. Use

```
create sequence my_seq
```

> The optional clause `CACHE` cache specifies how many sequence numbers are to be preallocated and stored in memory for faster access. The minimum value is 1 (only one value can be generated at a time, i.e., **no cache**), and this is also the default.